# How to add a DLL reference to a ASP.NET C# web application (the dll is a wrapper for underlying c libraries)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll, wrapper

I have to use a third party dll (called Jedox.Palo.Comm.dll)
This dll in turn references two more components - 1. libpalo_ng.dll & 2. libpalo2.dll
These two are not .net assemblies, rather they are c++ libraries.
The Jedox.Palo.Comm.dll is a .Net wrapper for these underlying c++ libraries.

Now when I create a console app, simply placing the other 2 dll's in the bin works
But what do I do in a web app. The placing file in bin doesn't seem to work
Adding references to the 2 dll's in web.config throws an error(not valid assembly)
Otherwise if I exclude the 2 dlls, I get a FileNotFound Exception for Jedox.Palo.Comm.dll or one of its dependencies was not found.

Contact me for any further clarifications!

Thanks & Regards
Indrajit

Comment: Put them in the system32 directory? (or syswow64 for 32bit on 64bit windows)

Comment: Well that did the trick! Thanks a ton! Been stuck for hours now, and kind of embarrassed at how simple the solution was!
Thanks & Regards
Indrajit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple adding the two dlls, libpalo_ng.dll & libpalo2.dll to the SysWOW64 directory did the trick! Thank you Alex K!